# Changing the alert title and message

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have made my app as an enterprise app on request from apple but want to change this message how can i change that.

[image]

Comment: How about showing us some code, let's see what you have tried so far?

Comment: That's a system message, not sure you can change it's contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't, that's a system message created and handled by iOS.